Two Kafka topics, maximum number of customers
I have a following setup. My Kafka consumer is subscribed to 2 topics.Each topic has 3 partitions. I was expecting, that I can create up to 6 consumers with the same consumer group id (one per partition of all topics). However, if I create more than 3 consumers, the number of consumers displayed in Confluent GUI is always 3.
So I'm confused why I can't have 6 consumers in the same group in this scenario.
